# Javascript cookies. path is not set

Tags: javascript, cookies, path

I have written the following function for setting a cookie.Here $.$domain holds domain name .

```
 function $cookie(name,value,lifeTime,path,domain,secure){//lifetime in hours
        if(typeof name == 'undefined' ||  name == '' ){

            alert('ERROR !!!\n Name of the cookie is not passed \n');
            return false;
        }

        if(typeof value == 'undefined'){

            alert('ERROR !!!\n Value of the cookie '+name+' is not passed \n');
            return false;
        }
        var c_ = name +'='+escape(value)+';';

            if(typeof lifeTime != 'undefined'&&lifeTime != ''){
               var life = new Date();
               lifeTime<1&&lifeTime>0life.setMinutes(life.getMinutes()+lifeTime*60):life.setHours(life.getHours()+lifeTime);
               life = life.toUTCString();
               c_+='expires='+life+";";
        }
        else lifeTime = 'Unspecified';

        if(typeof domain != 'undefined' &&  domain != '' )
               c_+= 'domain='+domain+';';
        else 
            domain = $.$domain;
        if(secure == 1 )
           c_ += 'secure=secure;';//secure 
        else 
                        secure = 0;
        if(typeof path != 'undefined' && path != '')
             c_ += 'path='+path+';';
        else 
                       path = '/';
        document.cookie = c_;
        this.$name = name;
        this.$value = value;
        this.$life = lifeTime;
        this.$domain = domain;
        this.$secure= secure;
        this.$path = path;
        if(!$.$COOKIE)
          $.$COOKIE = {};
        if(lifeTime<0)
        {   
            var t;
            if(t = $.$COOKIE[name])
            {
                delete t.$name;
                delete t.$value;
                delete t.$life;
                delete t.$domain;
                delete t.$secure;
                delete t.$path;
                delete $.$COOKIE[name];
            }
        }
        else
        $.$COOKIE[name] = this;

        return this;
    }
           var a = new $cookie('a2',6,1,'./scripts','');
```

$.$COOKIE holds all the cookies set by the domain..
scripts is a directory in my root directory..
   After a is created ,i viewed the cookie in Google chrome,But the path is not set.It is set to my / directory .Why is this happening

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
 if(typeof domain != 'undefined' &&  domain != '' )
        c_+= 'domain='+domain+';';
        else 
        domain = $.$domain;
```

should be

```
 if(typeof domain != 'undefined' &&  domain != '' )
        c_+= 'domain='+domain+';';
        else 
        c_+= 'domain='+$.$domain+';';
```

Comment: :If domain is not specified in document.cookie  domain will be the  domain of page from which cookie is set?Am i right?
That's why i didn't add that to document.cookie.It is added only if user specifies a domain

Comment: I understood that $.$domain is global and that you want to use that value for domain.